# Xcode "no such file or directory" if filename contains $$ sign?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Using xcode 6 and including files with names like `Some$$Class.h` and `Some$$Class.m` leads to problems. Xcode shows to error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/test/Some$ClassX.m'
clang: error: no input files
```

**How can I force Xcode to handle files with `$$`in its name correctly?**

Comment: A good idea is not to use these symbols that are used during preprocessing.

Comment: @Schemetrical I cannot avoid using these symbols.

Comment: Try using backslashes "\" to delimit the characters.

Comment: @Schemetrical could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: What? You cannot avoid that? Why?

Comment: @Schemetrical As I said the fines and its name is generated. Please answer my question if you can and do not ask different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very! dirty hack.

If you look to the error message, you can see that the build process of Xcode replaces the `$$` of `Some$$Class.m` with a single `$`. (Obviously there is no problem with `Some$$Class.h`) It is an escape sequence.

`Some$$Class.m` -> `Some$Class.m`

Therefore you can use `Some$$$$Class.m` to get `Some$$Class.m`.

1. Simply add an (empty) File with the name `Some$$$$Class.m` to your project to show Xcode that it exists. You have to do this once.
2. Generate your `Some$$Class.m` as you did as many times as you want.

When building Xcode will believe that it compiles and links `Some$$$$Class.m`, but in fact compiles and builds `Some$$Class.m`.

But you should really, really avoid these names. If the files are generated automatically it should be possible to rename them automatically.